# SQLite Database Query ordered result

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Hy,
I have a sqllite table similiar to this:

```
nr. | Name  
 4  | And  
 1  | Osd  
 6  | Edf  
 7  | Osd  
 6  | And  
 2  | Edf  
 3  | And
```

I need to Order the data by Name so it wil be in groups and then order every group based on the first nr in that group. So after the query the result should look like this:

```
nr. | Name  
 1  | Osd  ->First goup, it has nr =  1  
 7  | Osd  
 2  | Edf  ->Second goup, it has nr =  2  
 6  | Edf  
 3  | And  ->Third goup, it has nr = 3  
 4  | And  
 6  | And
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
SELECT nr, Name FROM (
  SELECT nr, Name, (
    SELECT MIN(nr) FROM _table_ AS _ WHERE Name=_table_.Name
  ) AS _min FROM _table_
) ORDER BY _min, nr
```

Check it in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/674bf/5.

EDIT: if `_table_` is in fact a union of tables, 3 options:

1) Create a view, so query will still work:

```
CREATE VIEW _table_ AS SELECT * FROM _table1_ UNION ALL SELECT * FROM _table2_
```

2) Replace `_table_` in previous query with table union:

```
SELECT nr, Name FROM (
  SELECT nr, Name, (
    SELECT MIN(nr) FROM (
      SELECT * FROM _table1_ UNION ALL SELECT * FROM _table2_
    )  AS _ WHERE Name=_table_.Name
  ) AS _min FROM (
    SELECT * FROM _table1_ UNION ALL SELECT * FROM _table2_
  ) AS _table_
) ORDER BY _min, nr
```

3) With, maybe, some optimization (I said maybe!):

```
SELECT _un.* FROM (
  SELECT * FROM _table1_
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM _table2_
) AS _un
JOIN (
  SELECT Name, MIN(nr) AS _min FROM (
    SELECT * FROM _table1_
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM _table2_
  ) GROUP BY Name
) AS _min ON _un.Name=_min.Name
ORDER BY _min, _un.nr
```

Comment: sqlite cannot execute this query, it gives me error, and from what i am seeing i think that it has something missing. Thank you for your quick post.

Comment: In the ORDER BY statement change Min to Name

Comment: Ups, forgot one `FROM table`! Check it now.

Comment: Thank you, that is what i needed. I have another problem, instead of _table_ i have a UNION of two tables http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d2c41/3

Comment: The third option is the fastest by far from the others,  i have a union with 3500 rows, 1 and 2 options take minutes to respond, the third takes a blink of an eye, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NAME, ID
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY  NAME, ID
```

Comment: This gives me just the first element in group, i need all the elements

Comment: Can you please say this what you want (query edited)

Comment: No, it does not order the groups based on the first nr in that group. LS_dev answer is almost complete, the missing part is "SELECT nr, Name, (SELECT MIN(nr) FROM table AS _ WHERE Name=table.Name)"+"FROM table" - the second select did not have a "FROM". But i still have a problem, instead of table i have a union from two select